# convert years and weeks to date in sql msaccess

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

how to convert text to date in sql as listed below?

> Y12-W01 to 20120102
>
> Y12-W02 to 20120109
>
> Y12-W03 to 20120116

and so on...

i use ms-access.

thank you in advance
regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate function, try this SQL example:

```
SELECT FieldName, DateAdd("ww",CDbl(Mid([FieldName],6,2))-1,DateSerial(Mid([FieldName],2,2),1,1)) AS ConvDate
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method would be to make a table of dates, with one row for each week.  One field would be the source format Y12-W01 and the 2nd field would be the resulting date 20120102.  Join your source data to this table on the 1st field and use the 2nd field as the date in further sql or queries.

Comment: thats what i did, but is there any sql to convert it?

Comment: what do you mean by "convert it"?  Do you want to change the data in the source table?  Or do you need a new table with the 20120102 date format in it?

Comment: yup the source data is Y12-W03 and i would like to change it to 20120102

Comment: Have you used an UPDATE query?  That would be the most direct - and if you need the SQL code, you can write the update query and then look at the SQL code it generates.  For the update query, just join the 2 tables, specifiy the date field in the source data and put the converted date field in the "Update to" row of the query grid.

Comment: I don't think so - the Yxx-Wxx format doesn't seem to be a standard date format and doesn't covert exactly to a yymmdd format, since the day isn't specified in the week number.  I think you need a table to get the appropriate yymmdd values, and an update query to put it back into your source table if you really need to store it there.

Comment: Yes, you can make a function to convert that date.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your Week and Year out of your field.  I'll let you figure out that one.  ;o)

Once you have the Week and Year, pass them into this function:

```
Function GetWeekStart(weekNum As Integer, yr As Integer) As Date

    GetWeekStart = DateSerial(yr, 1, 1 + (weekNum * 7) - 6 - Weekday(DateValue("1/1/" & yr)))

End Function
```